# Webpack Hot-Reload fails with "Unexpected token '['. Expected opening '{' at the start of a class body."

Tags: reactjs, webpack, motion, hot-reload

I'm using this [Boilerplate](https://github.com/HashemKhalifa/webpack-react-boilerplate) with React, Webpack, Babel & Hot-Reloading.
Everything was working fine, until I tried adding [Chakra-UI](https://chakra-ui.com)

Now, loading fails because hot-reloading can't import one of Chakra-UI's imports.
`SyntaxError: Unexpected token '['. Expected opening '{' at the start of a class body.` is the error I am getting.
[image: Browser Console Error]

I believe this is the file causing the error:

````
import { createMotionComponent } from '../../motion/index.js';
import { Drag } from '../../motion/features/drag.js';
import { Gestures } from '../../motion/features/gestures.js';
import { Exit } from '../../motion/features/exit.js';
import { Animation } from '../../motion/features/animation.js';
import { AnimateLayout } from '../../motion/features/layout/Animate.js';
import { MeasureLayout } from '../../motion/features/layout/Measure.js';
import { createDomMotionConfig } from './utils/create-config.js';
import { createMotionProxy } from './motion-proxy.js';

var allMotionFeatures = [
    MeasureLayout,
    Animation,
    Drag,
    Gestures,
    Exit,
    AnimateLayout,
];
/**
 * HTML & SVG components, optimised for use with gestures and animation. These can be used as
 * drop-in replacements for any HTML & SVG component, all CSS & SVG properties are supported.
 *
 * @public
 */
var motion = /*@__PURE__*/ createMotionProxy(allMotionFeatures);
/**
 * Create a DOM `motion` component with the provided string. This is primarily intended
 * as a full alternative to `motion` for consumers who have to support environments that don't
 * support `Proxy`.
 *
 * ```javascript
 * import { createDomMotionComponent } from "framer-motion"
 *
 * const motion = {
 *   div: createDomMotionComponent('div')
 * }
 * ```
 *
 * @public
 */
function createDomMotionComponent(key) {
    return createMotionComponent(createDomMotionConfig(allMotionFeatures, key, false));
}

export { createDomMotionComponent, motion };
````

However, when I remove the "HotModuleReplacementPlugin" from the Webpack config in order to disable hot-reloading, everything works just fine. Is there something I am missing (maybe a babel plugin that is doing something strange?) or have I come across a bug in react-hot-loader?